# Assign a String content to a new String in Java from parameter

Tags: java, string, netbeans, warnings

Having this method

```
void doSomething(String input)
{
   //trick for create new object instead of reference assignment
   String workStr= "" + input; 

   //work with workStr
}
```

Which is the java way for doing that?

**Edit**

- if I use input variable as input=something then Netbeans warns about assigning a value
  to a method parameter
- If I create it with new String(input) it warns about using String constructor

Perhaps the solution is not to assign nothing to input, or just ignore the warning..

Comment: Why would you want a copy of the object?

Comment: What work is being done? You can't change `input` as `String` instances are immutable. When you first need a modified version of `input` just save it to `workStr` at that point.

Comment: +1 for Oli's comment - I can think of absolutely no useful reason to explicitly create a new String.  You're almost certainly not getting the advantage you expect from doing this.

Comment: OK, I will explain: Netbeans warns about "assignment to method parameter", well, then I want to use the value but not the same variable name, then Copying the object for "code clean", is a resource waste, but I was just following warnings to see if it's possible to meet them

Comment: @Hernán Ah, OK.  Still, you can do this by pure assignment without requiring an additional string *object*: `String workStr = input` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle yes, is the same object, but is enough to deceive the warner

Answer (score 5):

```
String copy = new String(original);
```

> Initializes a newly created String object so that it represents the same sequence of characters as the argument; in other words, the newly created string is a copy of the argument string. Unless an explicit copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is unnecessary since Strings are immutable.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(java.lang.String)

Comment: That's the first attempt, but Netbeans warning about "String constructor invocation" and if I let Netbeans to do the auto refactoring it assign references, I think that's a bug?

Comment: I guess making a copy of a String is not a common occurrence, and that's why Netbeans warns you.

Comment: @Hernán - Netbeans is broadly right, there's no reason to take a copy, and assigning references will achieve the same thing with less memory usage.  Can you give an example of why you think it's a bug, i.e. some code that would behave differently?

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle I agree, but some warnings are contradictory, see my question comment

Comment: +1 good to quote the docs. @AndrzejDoyle: Some cases it will use less memory to take a copy... :-)

Answer (score 4):

`String`s in java are immutable, which means you cannot change the object itself (any operation returning a string (e.g. substring) will return a new one).

This means there is no need to create a new object for `String`s, as there is no way for you to modify the original.  Any attempt to do so will just result in wasted memory.

Assigning references is only a problem when the objects in question are mutable, because changes in one object will reflect in all other copies of the same reference.